# How to get formatted custom price

Tags: event-observer, price, custom-prices

I have set my product custom price in an observer..

```
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(9.99);
$item->setCustomPrice(9.99);
```

I can output the price value correclty like so:

```
echo $item->getOriginalPrice();
// 9.99
```

But when I try to output it formatted, it gives me the original price.

```
$finalPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
// £19.99
```

I tried

```
$finalPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('custom_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

But that gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for price with currency to display.

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

   $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); 

   $finalPrice = $priceHelper->currency($product->getCustomPrice(), true, false);
```